# Clone String to Specific Lifetime

Tags: rust, ownership-semantics

I'm currently trying to write a little command line app in Rust and I've hit a wall with lifetimes.

```
extern crate clap;
use self::clap::{App, Arg};
use std::env;

impl<'p> Params<'p> {
    fn get_username_arg<'r>() -> Arg<'r, 'r> {
        let mut arg = Arg::with_name("Username")
            .short("u")
            .long("username")
            .takes_value(true);
        match env::var("USERNAME") {
            Ok(username) => {
                // How do I pass `username` to default_value?
                arg.default_value(username)
            }
            Err(e) => arg.required(true),
        }
    }
    // More code below...
}
```

The problem is that I'm trying to pass `username` to the default value method, which requires a `str` with a lifetime of `'r`. I tried cloning but I can't figure how to tell it what the lifetime of the clone is going to be. I tried something along the following lines:

```
let cln = (&*username).clone::<'r>();
arg.default_value(username)
```

For some reason its now telling me that `username` doesn't live long enough, even though it shouldn't matter since I cloned the data.

So my question is, how do I make this compile?

EDIT: I'd like to add that its important to me that the signature stays the same aside from the lifetime parameters. I don't mind doing expensive operations such as cloning to make this work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[malbarbo has provided some good solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37503332/155423), but I'd like to discuss some aspects of the non-working code.

Let's start at the function signature:

```
fn get_username_arg<'r>() -> Arg<'r, 'r> {
```

This says "for *any* lifetime that the **caller** of this function picks, I will return an `Arg` that contains references that will last that long". That's a pretty difficult promise to uphold, as the caller could request something that meets the `'static` lifetime, a value that lasts *longer than the call to `main`*! In fact, the only way that you could meet the obligation of "any lifetime" is to return something that is `'static`.

This is a very good sign that there is going to be a problem. See also [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423), which shows this case as a constructor. Many people jump to attempting to return the `String` along with the `&str`, so that answer might short-circuit that avenue as well. ^_^

> `username` doesn't live long enough, even though it shouldn't matter since I cloned the data.

`username` has a very specific lifetime and it's finite. If you look at a piece of code, it's generally straight-forward to find out the lifetime of an object: it's the scope of the block that the variable lives in without moving. In your example, `username` only lives during the block that's part of the match arm `Ok(username) => { // }`. As soon as that block exits, the value is destroyed.

> `clone` in this case has a signature of `<'s>clone() -> &'s str` if you remove elisions (and reify `Self`) according to my very limited understanding of Rust in general.

`env::var` returns a `Result<String, VarError>`, and you access the `Ok` variant, making `username` a `String`. The [`String` implementation of `clone`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.clone) takes a `&String` and returns a `String`. I'm not sure where the `-> &'s str` would come from.

> So if I clone with `clone::<'r>()` it should force the lifetime...

This is a *very* common mistake. Check out [Do Rust lifetimes influence the semantics of the compiled program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32359619/155423) (and maybe [Why are explicit lifetimes needed in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31609137/155423)) for some background information. You **cannot** change the lifetime of something other than by rewriting your code to make the referred-to value have a larger scope. The lifetime syntax reflects how long the variable lives, it *does not control it*. There's no (safe) way to "force" a lifetime.

> `(&*username).clone` has that signature I mean

If we dereference and re-reference a `String`, we end up with a `&str`. That `&str` will have a lifetime that corresponds to how long the `String` lives. This makes sense because the `&str` is just pointing to the `String`. When the `String` is deallocated, the `&str` would be pointing at memory that is no longer in a valid state.

Comment: I am aware of that, which is why I'm cloning the value. `clone` in this case has a signature of `<'s>clone() -> &'s str` if you remove elisions(and reify `Self`) according to my very limited understanding of Rust in general. So if I clone with `clone::<'r>()` it should force the lifetime...

Comment: @JonathanBoudreau added more.

Comment: `(&*username).clone` has that signature I mean.

Answer (score 3):

[`Arg::default_value`](http://kbknapp.github.io/clap-rs/clap/struct.Arg.html#method.default_value) takes a `&str` as parameter, this means that the string is not stored in `Arg`, it is stored somewhere else. So the `&str` value must outlive the `Arg` that keeps the reference. If you use a `&str` obtained from a `String` value created in `get_username_arg` (that's the case for `username`), the `Arg` will outlive the `&str` (will live outside the `get_username_arg` while the `&str` lives only in the `Ok` block), so this generates a compiler error.

One option is to pass the default username as a parameter:

```
extern crate clap;
use self::clap::Arg;
use std::env;

pub struct Params;

impl Params {
    fn get_username_arg(default: Option<&str>) -> Arg {
        let arg = Arg::with_name("Username")
            .short("u")
            .long("username")
            .takes_value(true);
        if let Some(d) = default {
            arg.default_value(d)
        } else {
            arg.required(true)
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    // type can be omitted
    let username: Option<String> = env::var("USERNAME").ok();
    // username.as_ref() produces Option<&String>
    // map(String::as_str) produces Some(&str) from Some(&String)
    // or None from None
    let arg = Params::get_username_arg(username.as_ref().map(String::as_str));
}
```

Note that `username` is declared before `arg`, so `username` outlives `arg`.

---

> I'd like to add that its important to me that the signature stays the same aside from the lifetime parameters. I don't mind doing expensive operations such as cloning to make this work.

You do not show the `Params` definition, but it seems that it is just a "name space" for some functions. If this is the case, you can change these functions to receive `&self` as parameter (I know this is changing the signature, but the logic for creating args will stay in `Params`), and store `username` in `Params`:

```
extern crate clap;
use self::clap::Arg;
use std::env;

pub struct Params {
    username: Option<String>,
}

impl Params {
    fn new() -> Params {
        Params {
            username: env::var("USERNAME").ok(),
        }
    }

    fn get_username_arg(&self) -> Arg {
        let arg = Arg::with_name("Username")
            .short("u")
            .long("username")
            .takes_value(true);
        if let Some(d) = self.username.as_ref().map(String::as_str) {
            arg.default_value(d)
        } else {
            arg.required(true)
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let params = Params::new();
    let arg = params.get_username_arg();
}
```

Comment: My goal is to keep things organized in a way that all of the logic for the `Arg` creation stays in the `get_username_arg` function. Aside from the lifetimes I would prefer the signature stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37500808/4752169) explains what the problem is.

A solution here would be to retrieve the user name (if any) so that you have it as a `String` you can then take a reference on.

```
let user_name = match env::var("USERNAME") {
    Ok(user_name) => Some( user_name ),
    Err(_) => None,
} ;
// Now we can take a reference on the user name String (if any) that can live
// long enough for the arg.
let arg = match user_name {
    Some(ref name) => arg.default_value(name),
    None => arg.required(true),
} ;
```

Working example:

```
extern crate clap ;

use std::env;
use clap::* ;

fn main() {
    let arg = Arg::with_name("Username")
        .help("The user name")
        .short("u")
        .long("username")
        .takes_value(true);

    let user_name = match env::var("USERNAME") {
        Ok(user_name) => Some(user_name),
        Err(_) => None,
    };

    let arg = match user_name {
        Some(ref name) => arg.default_value(name),
        None => arg.required(true),
    };

    let app = App::new("Test").arg(arg);

    let matches = app.get_matches();

    match matches.value_of("username") {
        Some(name) => println!("name: \"{}\"", name),
        None => println!("no name :("),
    }
}
```

Comment: Right, I forgot to mention my solution is not wrapped in a function, it's just right where you construct the `Arg` and the `App`.